# uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function on .empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting uncaught type error undefined is not a function on .empty() method. The code is

```
title: "Criteria: "+ (criteriaText.empty() ? (criteriaIncludeText.empty()? criteriaExcludeText : criteriaIncludeText) : criteriaText)
```

In the above code criteriaText  and criteriaIncludeText are having values. I could see that in my alert message. Version of jQuery used is 1.7 . I am not really sure why it is giving uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function when there is proper value. COuld some one please help?

**Edit**

These variable are getting their values, by following code.

```
var criteriaText = jQuery(".categorySelect option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text(); 
var criteriaIncludeText = jQuery(".categorySelectInclude option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text();
var criteriaExcludeText = jQuery(".categorySelectExclude option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text();
```

Comment: I think instead of `criteriaText.empty()` you need to use `criteriaText.length == 0`, Check string as some text

Comment: this error happens the object has value, but does not have the function

Comment: `function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}` I would use this to check if empty

Comment: To commenters above: empty() (in jquery) doesn't check if a string is empty, it `Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM`. [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) Back to the question: are `criteriaText` and `criteriaIncludeText` the `id`'s of input elements? How did you reference them? In order to add the jQuery methods to your elements, you'd have to 'get' them from within jQuery. I'm not sure what `empty()` returns by the way, that might be the actual problem at hand!!

Comment: @GitaarLAB. criteria text and criteriaIncludeText are variables . We are assigning values to them by taking text of a id. var criteriaText = jQuery(".categorySelect option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text();
  
  var criteriaIncludeText = jQuery(".categorySelectInclude option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text();
  var criteriaExcludeText = jQuery(".categorySelectExclude option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use [jQuery's `empty` method](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) on a string (instead of a HTML DOM element):

For example:

```
var criteriaText = jQuery(".categorySelect option[value='"+categoryId+"']").text();
```

However, jQuery doesn't provide that method on a string so you are trying to execute `()` a function that doesn't exist (aka, not delivered by jQuery's prototype chain).

It appears you just want to check if the value is empty (in your ternary statement):

```
title: "Criteria: "+ (criteriaText.empty() ? (criteriaIncludeText.empty()? criteriaExcludeText : criteriaIncludeText) : criteriaText)
```

However, jQuery's `empty()` method 'Removes all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM' and returns object `jQuery` (that evaluates to true):

```
alert($('#elementId').empty()?'yes':'no');  
// object jQuery is an object, object coerces to TRUE
```

Now, you are in luck, as an empty string already coerced to `false`, so you can leave off the `.empty()` part in your ternary, done!

Answer (score 1):

[.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) is jquery function which apply on jquery objects to make them empty like `.html('')`. 
Your text variables are not jquery objects but simple strings that will return false when empty, therefore you can try:

```
title: "Criteria: "+ (criteriaText || criteriaIncludeText || criteriaExcludeText);
```